# What is this C program doing? Integer Arithmetic**

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic

It is returning 1 despite what the values of x and y are. I'm not understanding how or why. I copied a program from my textbook so this isn't something I wrote. We are currently studying integer arithmetic.

Can someone please explain what this code is doing? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int uadd_ok(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
unsigned sum = x+y;
return sum >=y;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
int x = 1, y = 5;

printf("Answer is: %d\n", uadd_ok(x,y));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are times it'll return 0; for example if `x = UINT_MAX` and `y = 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `sum >= y` is a boolean, and thus it gets converted to either `0` or `1` depending on its value. Since `x` and `y` are unsigned, assuming there's no overflow you will always have `x + y >= y`, so the result is always true, and thus `1`.

(Presumably the point of the function is to check whether an overflow occurred...)

Comment: Ok I understand now. If I wanted it to overflow how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @CarlosCarrillo: Add two very large numbers, like `-1` and `-1`.

Comment: (The result of which is of course `-2`. That might *look* unsurprising, but is should be a very big surprise. Until you really understand unsigned arithmetic, and then it's perfectly clear again. But in any event, `-2` is less than `-1`.)

Answer (score 2):

Since x and y are unsigned, they are both positive. The sum of x and y therefore has to be greater than y. So sum >= y is true, which gets converted to 1 because you formatted it as %d.